# Swift 2 + Xcode 7: Sound playing when wrong button is pressed

Tags: ios, swift, audio, swift2

I have a problem with a little App I am programming & learning with. I finally added a sound that it's supposed to play when you press a Stepper, and it does, the problem is that it's also playing when you press a different button.
I honestly have no idea why it happens and how to fix it.
Any help?

here's my code:

ViewONE (here the button that shouldn't be playing the audio file is "BotonLetsBegin"

```
//
//  ViewONE.swift
//  Simple Score
//
//  Created by Juan Francisco Mellado on 10/1/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Juan Francisco Mellado. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import UIKit

class ViewONE: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {


    override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
        return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var ScrollViewOne: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var teamRedName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var initScoreRed: UITextField!

    @IBAction func BotonLetsBeginAction(sender: UIButton) {

    }

    @IBOutlet weak var BotonLetsBegin: UIButton!


    @IBOutlet weak var teamBlueName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var initScoreBlue: UITextField!


    @IBAction func userTappedBackground(sender: AnyObject) {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }

    @IBAction func userTappedThisView(sender: AnyObject) {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let DestViewController : ViewTwo = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewTwo

        // Cambiamos los valores si no existen a 0

        if(initScoreRed.text == ""){
            initScoreRed.text = "0"
        }
        if(initScoreBlue.text == ""){
            initScoreBlue.text = "0"
        }
        //---------

        DestViewController.RedName = teamRedName.text!
        DestViewController.BlueName = teamBlueName.text!
        DestViewController.RedScore = initScoreRed.text!
        DestViewController.BlueScore = initScoreBlue.text!

    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue
        UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
        BotonLetsBegin.layer.cornerRadius = 5

        self.initScoreBlue.delegate = self
        self.initScoreRed.delegate = self

    }

    let TEXT_FIELD_LIMIT = 3

func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    switch textField {
    case initScoreBlue:
        return (textField.text?.utf16.count ?? 0) + string.utf16.count - range.length <= TEXT_FIELD_LIMIT
    case initScoreRed:
        return (textField.text?.utf16.count ?? 0) + string.utf16.count - range.length <= TEXT_FIELD_LIMIT
    case teamBlueName:
        return (textField.text?.utf16.count ?? 0) + string.utf16.count - range.length <= 25
    case teamRedName:
        return (textField.text?.utf16.count ?? 0) + string.utf16.count - range.length <= 25
    default:
        return true
    }
}

    //For Swift 1.2
    //return count((textField.text ?? "").utf16) + count(string.utf16) - range.length <= TEXT_FIELD_LIMIT

    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return false
    }
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {

        if (textField == initScoreBlue){
            ScrollViewOne.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, 250), animated: true)
        }
        if (textField == teamBlueName){
            ScrollViewOne.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, 250), animated: true)
        }
        if (textField == teamRedName){
            ScrollViewOne.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, 100), animated: true)
        }
        if (textField == initScoreRed){
            ScrollViewOne.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, 100), animated: true)
        }
    }
    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        ScrollViewOne.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, 0), animated: true)
    }

    // - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    //{
    //[textField resignFirstResponder];
    //}

}
```

Here is ViewTwo where the steppers are

```
//
//  ViewTWO.swift
//  Simple Score
//
//  Created by Juan Francisco Mellado on 9/29/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Juan Francisco Mellado. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import UIKit
import AVFoundation


class ViewTwo : UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate {

    override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
        return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
    }

    /// Actions de sonido -------
    @IBAction func stepperSoundRed(sender: UIStepper) {
        audioPlayer.play()
    }
    @IBAction func stepperSoundBlue(sender: UIStepper) {
        audioPlayer.play()
    }
    /////////////////////////

    // el nombre del equipo Blue
    @IBOutlet weak var teamBlueTextLabel: UILabel!
    var BlueName = String()

    // nombre del equipo rojo
    @IBOutlet weak var teamRedTextLabel: UILabel!
    var RedName = String()

    // score inicial del equipo rojo
    @IBOutlet weak var RedScoreLabel: UILabel!
    var RedScore = String()

    // score initcial equipo azul
    @IBOutlet weak var BlueScoreLabel: UILabel!
    var BlueScore = String()

    // que funcionen los Steppers
    @IBOutlet weak var RedStepperUI: UIStepper!
    @IBOutlet weak var BlueStepperUI: UIStepper!

    // Botón Done
    @IBOutlet weak var BotonDone: UIButton!

    @IBAction func BlueStepperValueChange(sender: UIStepper) {
        BlueScoreLabel.text  = Int(sender.value).description
    }

    @IBAction func RedStepperValueChange(sender: UIStepper) {
        RedScoreLabel.text  = Int(sender.value).description

    }
   // archivos de sonidos
    var sound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("ping2", ofType: "mp3")!)
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    required init? (coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        do {
            try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: sound, fileTypeHint: nil)
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            audioPlayer.delegate = self
            audioPlayer.play()

        } catch {
            // Errors here
        }
    }

    // VIEW DID LOAD
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        // No se para que es esto??
        super.viewDidLoad()

        BotonDone.layer.cornerRadius = 5

        // Checamos si están vacios los nombres
        if BlueName.isEmpty {
            BlueName = "TEAM BLUE"
        }

        if RedName.isEmpty {
            RedName = "TEAM RED"
        }


        // Proseguimos a asignarlos a las Labels

        teamBlueTextLabel.text = BlueName
        teamRedTextLabel.text = RedName
        RedScoreLabel.text = RedScore
        BlueScoreLabel.text = BlueScore


        // Aqui vemos el Red +/-
        RedStepperUI.wraps = true
        RedStepperUI.autorepeat = false
        RedStepperUI.value = Double(RedScore)!
        RedStepperUI.maximumValue = 999

        // aqui vemos el Blue +/-
        BlueStepperUI.wraps = true
        BlueStepperUI.autorepeat = false
        BlueStepperUI.value = Double(BlueScore)!
        BlueStepperUI.maximumValue = 999

        //
        let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeLeft.rawValue
        UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
    }
    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is in init(...) method of ViewTwo. You create a player and call the play() method :

```
required init? (coder aDecoder: NSCoder){
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    do {
        try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: sound, fileTypeHint: nil)
        audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        audioPlayer.delegate = self

        audioPlayer.play() // this is your problem ;)

    } catch {
        // Errors here
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much. It worked, another thing. When I input a value to var BlueScore if it's bigger than 100 then anytime I presse the "+" stepper it goes back to 100... any idea why?